# KNN algorithm with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, knn, grid-search

Im trying to create a KNN model with GridSearchCV but am getting an error pertaining to param_grid: "ValueError: Invalid parameter classifier_leaf_size for estimator KNeighborsClassifier(). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.".

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

knn.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = knn.predict(x_test)

scores = cross_val_score(knn, x_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)

print('Training Accuracy - KNN Classification: ', knn.score(x_train, y_train))
print('Testing Accuracy - KNN Classification', knn.score(x_test, y_test))

plt.show()

#classification report
cr = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
print(cr, "\n")
```

```
#grid
estimator_KNN = KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto')
knn_grid_set_up = {'n_neigbors': (1,10,1),
                   'classifier_leaf_size': (20,40,1), 'p': (1,2),
                   'classifier_weights': ('uniform', 'distance')
                   }

grid_search_KNN = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=estimator_KNN,
    param_grid=knn_grid_set_up,
    scoring = 'accuracy',
    n_jobs = -1,
    cv = 5
)
knn_grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

What causes the error? I've read documentation, have tried various methods, but still can't understand what is going on